# Fixed nav bar is causing button within page not to work

Tags: css

I want my navigation bar to be fixed at the top, but when I put the css coding in, all the other buttons on my page stop working.

This is my CSS

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom:200px;
    padding:inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

I have tested it and the website works fine when I take this out.

Comment: add your HTML please

Comment: jsfiddle is good too.

Comment: could be the z-index is higher than the buttons so you might be clicking on the header instead of the buttons if the buttons are in a different element

Comment: @AleshaOleg, since it is affecting the whole site I am just adding the header HTML.  If there is other HTML I should post let me know.
https://jsfiddle.net/lynnk1977/8bLqtyr3/

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do with that code. at the moment you have told the header to cover the **whole** page *except* for the bottom 200px. I suspect that is *not* what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the since your layout is fixed and you are using the position properties and z-index that your #header is above everything else and putting an "invisible barrier" between where you click and the buttons underneath all buttons below 200px from the bottom of your screen should be clickable to see for yourself try adding a background color to see what is going on. Removing the top and left positions will help and if possible you might not even need to use the z index property depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I took your advice and it is still doing the same thing.